Ozoneless air ionisation
Is there some way to ionise air in way that removes or atleast decreases ozone production? Is some combination of electrode shape, electrode material, negative or positive voltage, dc or ac and frequency going to change the ratio of ozone to other charged molecules?
Basically, is ozone always created in fixed ratio compared to N2+ and O2- and other charged species so its unavoidable byproduct of air ionisation or is the ratio variable depending on some factors?
I am asking about operation in the low current region called dark discharge/townsend regime/corona.

Even if you cannot avoid creating it, ozone has very little residence time/distance once it is away from the source of ionization.  For example, ozone is created by UV rays in the outside air, but very little of that makes it into your home before recombining into O2

I guess if the energy involved is high enough to destroy any ozone that would solve the problem as you stated it, but I doubt that this is what you are really after. Maybe this question could better be answered at chemistry.stackexchange.com. Chemistry know about how to balance a reaction into preferring wanted products and reducing unwanted.

In the Townsend regime, ozone gets produced when electrical current flows through air and turns the oxygen molecules into ions. This is inevitable.
The only way to prevent oxygen (O2) from getting ionized (and hence reacting to form O3) when air begins to conduct is to remove the oxygen from the air first.
You can effectively scavenge the ozone out of that air by pulling it through a wad of damp steel wool after the fact, quickly converting the wet iron into oxides of iron- but this also scavenges the excited states of nitrogen too.
